# Error: This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely, not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly

Tags: solidity, remix, testnets, kovan

Injected web3
Kovan 42 network
Remix IDE
This is from the freecodecamp.org tutorial on youtube

Here is the code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Aggregator: ETH/USD
     * Address: 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
     */
    constructor() {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            /*uint80 roundID*/,
            int price,
            /*uint startedAt*/,
            /*uint timeStamp*/,
            /*uint80 answeredInRound*/
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your contract is fine.

My best guess is that you are trying to deploy the interface it is relying on instead of your contract.

So if your Remix looks like this on the deployment pane :

[image]

Just make sure to click on the "CONTRACT" submenu, to select PriceConsumerV3 :

[image]

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved BOTH problems by switching from Chrome to Brave Browser

1. I could not receive any test LINK from  https://faucets.chain.link/
2. I could not deploy this contract w/out getting an error message